# CodeIgniter 4 - Migrations is not making database table

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, migration

I make two migrations table User roles and Users.
When i am migrating it. it says done successfully both of them but just Users table is in the database no user role. Although database have created role_id as foreign key too but not user roles table in the database.

**Overall Picture**
[image]

**Migration table**
[image]

Below is my code for migrations

**User Roles**

```
<?php namespace App\Database\Migrations;

use CodeIgniter\Database\Migration;

class UserRoles extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->forge->addField([
            'role_id' => [
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'unsigned' => true,
                'auto_increment' => true
            ],
            'role' => [
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => 255
            ],
            'role_description' => [
                'type' => 'TEXT',
                'null' => true
            ],
            'created_at' => [
                'type' => 'timestamp',
                'default' => 'current_timestamp'
            ],
            'created_by' => [
                'type' => 'int',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'null' => true
            ],
            'updated_at' => [
                'type' => 'timestamp',
                'null' => true
            ],
            'updated_by' => [
                'type' => 'int',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'null' => true
            ],
            'deleted_at' => [
                'type' => 'timestamp',
                'null' => true
            ],
        ]);
        $this->forge->addKey('role_id', true);
        $this->forge->createTable('user_roles');
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function down()
    {
        $this->forge->dropTable('user_roles');
    }
}
```

**Users Migration Code**

```
<?php namespace App\Database\Migrations;

use CodeIgniter\Database\Migration;

class Users extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->db->disableForeignKeyChecks();
        $this->forge->addField([
            'user_id' => [
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'unsigned' => true,
                'auto_increment' => true
            ],
            'first_name' => [
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => 255
            ],
            'last_name' => [
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => 255
            ],
            'email' => [
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => 255
            ],
            'password' => [
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => 255
            ],
            'role_id' => [
                'type' => 'INT',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'unsigned' => true,
            ],
            'transaction_pin' => [
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => 255
            ],
            'created_by' => [
                'type' => 'int',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'null' => true
            ],
            'updated_at' => [
                'type' => 'timestamp',
                'null' => true
            ],
            'updated_by' => [
                'type' => 'int',
                'constraint' => 11,
                'null' => true
            ],
            'deleted_at' => [
                'type' => 'timestamp',
                'null' => true
            ],
        ]);
        $this->forge->addKey('user_id', true);
        $this->forge->addForeignKey('role_id', 'user_roles', 'role_id', 'cascade', 'null');
        $this->forge->createTable('users');
        $this->db->enableForeignKeyChecks();
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function down()
    {
        $this->db->disableForeignKeyChecks();
        $this->forge->dropTable('user_id');
        $this->db->enableForeignKeyChecks();
    }
}
```

Can Someone help me with this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced with the same issue. This is because migrate trying to create `user_roles` table before the `users` table and cannot add the foreign key because the `user_roles` table does not exist. I suggest you migrate the `users` table after the migrating the `user_roles` table.

You can migrate migration classes separately with the following command:

```
php spark migrate -g DB_NAME -n MIGRATION_CLASS_NAME
```

The documentation is [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/dbmgmt/migration.html).

Comment: I believe -g parameter is not DB_NAME, it is database group name from CI4 config.

Answer (score 1):

You might be facing this issue because of type => timestamp. Try without fields(updated_at and deleted_at).
I am also suffering from same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
public $defaultGroup = 'default';
```

specify the database connection.

and be sure u are in default connection in app/config/database.php

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a specific migration className:

```
php spark migrate className
```

also check: https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/cli/cli_commands.html